# Pandas extract columns from dataframe which are not present in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have foll 2 dataframes:

```
df_A

A    B    C    D
12   23   34   45
22   32   54   87
```

and,

```
df_B

B    C 
23   34
32   54
```

How do I select the columns in df_A which are not present in df_B, resulting in following dataframe (you can assume that df_B is a subset of df_A):

```
A    D
12   45
22   87
```

I tried this:

```
df_A[df_A.columns.values <> df_B.columns.values]
```

but it results in a KeyError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> df_A.columns.difference(df_B.columns)
Index(['A', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

will give you the columns, and you can do:

```
>>> cols = df_A.columns.difference(df_B.columns)
>>> df_A[cols]
    A   D
0  12  45
1  22  87
```

Comment: I just tried this and I still get all the columns to retrieve as opposed to just the difference, any idea why that could be?